# make even / odd(nth-child) divs in listview, with different sizes connect with eachother with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I am currently working on a responsive framework which contains a section that has max. 3 columns when the browser is not scaled. I use Pseudo selectors (nth) with these column to change the height of the odd divs. The responsiveness works like a charm, no problem there. The odd/even divs work fine, it behaves perfectly even when scaled down.

My problem is this:

I made a listview with divs because the intention was to make the even and the odd divs fit one below the other and next to each other seamlessly with negative top margins. That does not seem to work unfortunately. there are gaps that I can't seem to get rid of.

A mockup to clarify my intentions:

[Example](http://s27.postimg.org/701mkft3n/example_divlist.jpg)

I would like to have a full css solution for getting rid of the gaps but i'm afraid that's not possible unless there's something i'm totally missing.

Html:

```
 <section class="home">
                <p>It's&nbsp;<span id="demo"></span>&nbsp;today</p>                
                    <div class="work">
                        <div class="work_col-1-3">test1</div>
                        <div class="work_col-1-3">test2</div>
                        <div class="work_col-1-3">test3</div>
                        <div class="work_col-1-3">test4</div>
                        <div class="work_col-1-3">test5</div>
                        <div class="work_col-1-3">test6</div>
                        <div class="work_col-1-3">test7</div>
                        <div class="work_col-1-3">test8</div>
                        <div class="work_col-1-3">test9</div>
                        <div class="work_col-1-3">test10</div>
                        <div class="work_col-1-3">test11</div>
                        <div class="work_col-1-3">test12</div>                              
                      </div>
            </section>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {

.work_col-1-3 {
position:relative;
width: 33%;
height: 200px;
background-color:purple;
display:inline-block;
margin:-2px;
}

.work_col-1-3:nth-child(odd) {
position:relative;
background-color:orange;
margin:-2px;
height:300px;
```

}

Also here's a fiddle. The fiddle contains just the 3 column part of the css but it should fit in every state. ( 3-column, 2-column & 1-column but the 1 column is working already)

http://jsfiddle.net/Vishumahabir/tB7Aw/

The "section" element is a child object in an "article" element.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Zach, 

I've applied your solution and it works great! your Pinterest example is something I need to research and learn from. Thanks to your solution and example i'm able to recheck my code and tweak it where necessary. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the heights are set then you can use the following to do it, though it's very ugly especially if you add more elements

```
.tmcwork_col-1-3:nth-child(2n + 5), /* Select oranges after first line */
.tmcwork_col-1-3:nth-child(2n + 8) { /* Select purples after second line */
    top:-100px;        
}
.tmcwork_col-1-3:nth-child(2n + 11) { /* Select oranges after third line */
    top:-200px;        
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/tB7Aw/4/)

If the heights vary or you have a lot more elements it'd be easier to [look at an existing one](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout) and use a similar technique as them

Comment: Hi Zach, 

Thank you for your reply. The elements will have a fixed height so this is a great solution to my problem! Thank you very much for your insights and share it with me!

Comment: @Zilli If an answer is satisfactory, you can click the check mark to the left of the answer to mark it as correct (: This will give both people some reputation

Comment: Right! Thanks for the tip!